# How can you do multiple selection in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

In Sublime text you're able to highlight a word and then use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to select multiple instances of that word. I've looked around a bit but couldn't find out how to do that in SSMS, either via a tool or shortcut key. I could just keep using sublime but switching back and forth between multiple tabs and queries can get confusing.

**Multiple selection in Sublime Text:**
[image]

Comment: I use Alt + Select with Mouse - you can hold down ALT key and make a selection across multiple lines using mouse - also ALT + SHIFT with arrow keys should work - https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/04/ssms-alt-shift-trick/

Comment: Link 2 - http://sqlmag.com/blog/simple-sql-server-management-studio-trick-multiple-line-text-editing

Answer (score 4):

Either use Alt Select or use the find function - and either find + replace in selection or just to find all :)

Unfortunately it is not as straight forward as it is in Sublime.

Answer (score 3):

In SSMS 18, you can use for multiple selection the next occurrence: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this:

```
Control + F
type your term/word in the search term box
type your term/word in the replace term box
Click Replace All on the right - Alt + A
```

boom!

Answer (score 1):

Use alt+ shift+ down arrow in ssms.